# How remove array of arraylist using c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-3.0, arraylist

How to remove the array from arraylist

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[3000];
        int capacityForList = 2;

        int i = 0;
        int j;
        int k;

        arr[i] = new ArrayList();
        arr[i].Add("A");
        i++;
        arr[i] = new ArrayList();
        arr[i].Add("B");
        i++;
        arr[i] = new ArrayList();
        arr[i].Add("C");
        i++;
        arr[i] = new ArrayList();
        arr[i].Add("D");
        i++;
        arr[i] = new ArrayList();
        arr[i].Add("E");
        i++;
    }
}
```

from this i want remove arr[3]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't "remove" elements from an array in the same way that you can from a `List<T>` or an `ArrayList` - you can only *replace* elements. You can copy a whole chunk of an array using [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx), admittedly, but it's a bit ugly.

A better solution would be to change your code to use a `List<List<string>>`:

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "A" },
    new List<string> { "B" },
    new List<string> { "C" },
    new List<string> { "D" },
    new List<string> { "E" }
};

list.RemoveAt(3); // Removes the list containing "D"
```

However, whenever I see code using collections of collections, I get nervous... what's the *meaning* here? Could you perhaps change the "inner" list of strings to something more meaningful? If you could give us more information about the bigger picture, it would really help.

Oh, and try to avoid using the non-generic collections like `ArrayList`. Type safety is important :)

Answer (score 0):

A simplest thing to do is use `List<ArrayList>` instead of `ArrayList[]`, you can them simply call `arr.RemoveAt(3)`